# Projection for using ArcGIS as CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, cad

I want to use ArcGIS to map my apartment. How can I create a projection file (with which parameters)?

Comment: Are you tying in to a monument or is it an arbitrary 1:1 scale? And what are you using to "map" your an apartment...a laser scanner, tape, total stations, etc... If you are using a tape and it's not tied to a monument don't use a projection just draw the thing.

Comment: what is monument? I'm just looking for an arbitrary metric projection, like visio for example

Comment: If you don't need it mapped in real-world space, then you don't need a projection - just draw it.

Comment: Just draw with no projection is not working. Area/length calcs can be affected. I'd say use any local projection, pick any point near the house and go from here

Comment: Just draw it with a "paint" like program and annotate the measurements..GIS software is the wrong tool to solve this problem.  And if you are worried about dimensions being affected by the software then you are absolutely using the wrong tool for both the drafting and measuring.  Any errors you have will be tied to the surveyor the software is the least of your concerns.

Comment: Can you screen capture it to us ?

Comment: @PROBERT I haven't started drawing yet, I only took measurements on a paper

Comment: @Dan I want it o be vector so can't use paint. Would be using Visio or AutoCAD but I don't have a license, and for ArcGIS I do

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to improve it with any requested clarifications.  For example, it is not clear whether you are looking for someone to suggest a Projected Coordinate System to use or how to create a local coordinate system.

Comment: You might want to consider whether you even need a projection file.  If you're just mapping your apartment, use a local coordinate system.  If you intend--either now or later--to relate your map to other maps of different features or different areas, then indeed it is wise to be thinking of a useful coordinate system for that purpose. But this issue goes far beyond the mere creation of a "projection file."  Thus I concur with @PolyGeo's requests for more information.

Comment: @whuber looks like your comment is suitable to be an answer, although there is still a problem with both of your suggestions. No coordinate system is bad practice, tool will fail (read previous comments). Using a real world coordinate system will enforce rotating the flat to match the north and is an overkill. Can you please ask clear questions on what additional information would you require (for example, "would you like to relate the plan to a map, for example georeferencing it to ESPG:3857?"? (answer is no by the way).

Comment: I did not suggest using "no coordinate system." @PolyGeo listed some of the additional information that would help readers understand what you are asking for and decide how to respond appropriately. But there's no purpose to playing guessing games in these comments (which few people will read): if you would like to clarify your question, then please do so by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a projection if your coordinates are arbitrary.  If you are going to use a basemap to pick a corner of the building provided by Arcmap then you are stuck with WGS84.  Autocad offers free trial and complete student edition if you are a student.  There are many open source drafting programs to choose from but your question does not state an OS so I can't make a recommendation...either way that's an easy search and I am sure it has been covered here.

You could also draw it in paint or some other drawing program and geo-rectify the image in arcmap using satellite imagery.

Here is something to keep in mind:
GIS is a poor architectural drafting program and AutoCAD is a poor GIS program.

Comment: The reference to "WGS84" suggests some confusion between a datum and a coordinate system.